# reading directory and file name from a text file

Tags: c, file

i have a text file consists of the name and the directory of text files. for example: in a file with name "fileoutput.txt" i have the followings:

```
Desktop/textFinder/text.txt

Desktop/textFinder/text1.txt
```

now i am trying to read the file "fileoutput.txt" and doing process on text.txt and text1.txt . I used ``` FILE *fp = fopen("fileoutput.txt", "r"); ``readFindFile(fp); ``` in the main and l used the following code:

```
void readFindFile(FILE *fp)

{

int count = 1;
char buff[255];

while(fscanf(fp,"%s",buff)==1 )

{

FILE *fp1 = fopen(buff, "r");

printf("The file %s will be processed!\n", buff);
if( fp1 == NULL )

{

perror("Error while opening the file.\n");

exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

}

RW(fp1);// for doing process on  text.txt and text1.txt

}

fclose(fp);

}
```

when program reads fileoutput.txt then it cant process  Desktop/textFinder/text.txte and i give this error: not such file or directory.

could u please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Either your working directory is wrong or the relative path does not correspond to an actual file.

Comment: What's the content of `buff` at the time of the error? Does the current directory have a subdirectory named "Desktop"?

Answer (score 2):

Try to enter the full path to the list of files.
Note for windows it will be something like this:
`C:\Users\(user)\Desktop\textFinder\text1.txt`

and for Linux:

`/home/(user)/Desktop/textFinder/text1.txt`